# Mi CircleImageView no se ve circular

Tags: android, imagen, kotlin, studio

estoy trabajando en una app en Android Studio con Kotlin y quiero agregar una imagen de perfil, entonces decidí usar CircleImageView para ello, pero cuando lo llamo en el xml me sale error y solo se ve una imagen normal (no circular).

En la pagina del CircleImageView sale que tengo implementarlo en el Gradle, lo implemente y lo sincronize pero aun no funciona

Este es mi codigo xml, Aqui es donde tengo que agregar la imagen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.gallery.GalleryFragment">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="text@correo.com"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.116" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewMail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Nombre"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_name" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="122dp"
        android:layout_height="122dp"
        android:src="@drawable/DSC_0199" />






</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Y este es mi Gradle, donde implemente la dependencia que me decia

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ezdev.chepesdelivery"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.0'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'


}
```

Necesito que esa imagen sea circular para poder implementarlo con Firestore de Firebase para que los usuarios puedan subir sus fotos de perfiles

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta puedes agradecer con un voto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elimina esa librería. Entre tus dependencias ya tienes los material components que incluyen una `ShapeableImageView` que puede tomar cualquier forma, incluida la circular.

Primero declaras la forma en el archivo donde tengas los estilos. Buscalo en la carpeta `res/values/` normalmente se llama `styles.xml` o `themes.xml` y agrega esto:

```
<style name="circleImageView" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>
```

Luego en el atributo `app:shapeAppearanceOverlay` de la `ShapeableImageView` referencias la forma que creaste anteriormente

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    android:layout_width="122dp"
    android:layout_height="122dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/DSC_0199"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/circleImageView" />
```